# How to get calling origin in NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Can someone help us to add calling origin in NGINX header?

We need to whitelist calling origin on the basis of the origin (from where the request originated/triggered)

```
    location /some_filter_url {
            proxy_pass http://test-domain.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Origin {????? What should be used $http-origin is null};
    }
```

variable $http-origin giving us the value null while $host giving the current/original host.

Any Help will be appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Answer (score 1):

It is `$http_origin` with an underscore and not the dash.

Comment: Thanks Danila Vershinin 
but variable $http_origin yields the same result